# Is dict in python 3.6.1 auto-ordered?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I know in python(below version-3.6), elements(key-value-pairs) are not ordered, dictionary type objects dn't remember the position each key-value-pair was first added.so ,if we create a dictionary `d = {'banana': 3, 'apple': 4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}`,the order will be diffrent when we iterate it or print it   ,actually it wil be  `{'pear': 1, 'banana': 3, 'apple': 4, 'orange': 2}`.

But today, when I tried python 3.6.1 , and I saw ,if I created a dictionary `d = {'banana': 3, 'apple': 4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}` ,when I printed it ,the result will also be `{'banana': 3, 'apple': 4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}`.
So, my question is, is the dictionary type in python 3.6 different from before.

Comment: Yes. [11 more to go]